# Illusionary Mask + Double Face Cards

Tags: magic-the-gathering

What is the interaction between [Illusionary Mask](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Illusionary%20Mask) and Double Face Cards. Does the card enter face down and become a 2/2 creature? Is it colorless or the color of the face down face? Does it lose it's other abilities?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A face down double-faced card works just like any other face down card. It has the characteristics specified by the effect that put it face down, and none of the characteristics of the back face. This is specified in [rule 712.11](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Double-faced_card):

> If an effect allows a player to cast a double-faced card as a face-down creature spell, or if a double-faced card enters the battlefield face down, it will have the characteristics given to it by the rule or effect that caused it to be face down. That card remains hidden, using a face-down substitute card (see rule 714) and/or opaque sleeves. See rule 708, “Face-Down Spells and Permanents.”